# How to use condition for adding or removing closing tags containing htms in JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Fade tag which is animation tag under package react-reveal
I want to use `Fade` tag for the animation only when my mouse come under div tag else I don't want to animate the div `className=card-container` but
to do this I have to repeat the code div `className=card-container` like so
`{ isHover ? <Fade>div className="card-container"</Fade> : div className="card-container" }`

Is there alternative to do remove Fade tag only in simple way.

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Fade } from "react-reveal";


export default function CardSection() {
    const [isHover, setIsHover] = React.useState(false);

    function getIsHover() {
        setIsHover((prev) => !prev);
    }

    return(
        <CardSectionStyled>
            <div onMouseEnter={getIsHover}>
                <div className="card-container">
                    {/* Here I have to repeat p tag in order to add and remove Fade tag  */}
                    {isHover ? <Fade right duration={1500} delay={500}>
                        <div className="card-left">
                            <p>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </Fade> :
                        <div className="card-left">
                            <p>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    }
            </div>
        </CardSectionStyled>
    );
}

const CardSectionStyled = styled.section`
    .card-container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    }

    p {
      padding: 1.5rem 0;
    }
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

React elements are values (specifically, they're objects), you can put them in variables. So you can put that `div` in a variable (say, `cardLeft`) and then use that in the two places you need it:

```
export default function CardSection() {
    const [isHover, setIsHover] = React.useState(false);

    function getIsHover() {
        setIsHover((prev) => !prev);
    }

    // *** Put the React element for the `div` in a variable
    const cardLeft = (
        <div className="card-left">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab 
            </p>
        </div>
    );
    // *** Use `cardLeft` in the two places you need it below
    return(
        <CardSectionStyled>
            <div onMouseEnter={getIsHover}>
                <div className="card-container">
                    {isHover
                        ?   <Fade right duration={1500} delay={500}>
                                {cardLeft}
                            </Fade>
                        :   cardLeft
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </CardSectionStyled>
    );
}
```

*(I also added a missing `</div>`.)*

There are a dozen different ways to spin it. For instance:

```
export default function CardSection() {
    const [isHover, setIsHover] = React.useState(false);

    function getIsHover() {
        setIsHover((prev) => !prev);
    }

    let cardLeft = (
        <div className="card-left">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab 
            </p>
        </div>
    );
    if (isHover) {
        cardLeft = (
            <Fade right duration={1500} delay={500}>
                {cardLeft}
            </Fade>
        );
    }
    return(
        <CardSectionStyled>
            <div onMouseEnter={getIsHover}>
                <div className="card-container">{cardLeft}</div>
            </div>
        </CardSectionStyled>
    );
}
```